# Save GPX file to iCloud

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, ipad, icloud

1. I am developing an iphone app and in this i have a .gpx file. I want to save this file to iCloud but i don't have any idea about iCloud api in iOS 5.
   My question is that can we save .gpx files to iClould from iphone app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can save any file you want. This is limited only by the amount of free space in the user's iCloud account. Regarding the details of the implementation, the Apple iOS Developer Library is a good starting point:

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/iCloud/iCloud.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH5-SW1